# What’s the relation between local diagonalisation of Riemannian metrics and the eigenprojections for the representation matrix functions?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Recently, the topic of smooth diagonalisation of Riemannian metrics came to my interest. Namely, I've read through [this](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077303804) paper from Duke Math. J.
Volume 51, Number 2 (1984), 243-260 (unfortunately the document doesn't seem to be publicly available). In Theorem 4.2, they state and prove the following:

> Let $(M^3, g)$ be a three-dimensional $C^\infty$ Riemannian manifold. Then there is an atlas of $C^\infty$ coordinate charts for $M$ such that, in each chart, the metric is diagonal, i.e.
>
> $$d s^2 = \lambda_1(x, y, z) d x^2 + \lambda_2 (x, y, z) d y^2 + \lambda_3 (x, y, z) d z^2$$

They furthermore make a similar statement for the case $n = 2$, namely that for two-manifolds, one has always coordinates in which the metric locally takes the form

$$d s^2 = \lambda(x, y) (d x^2 + d y^2)$$

As someone for who Riemannian manifolds are a relatively fresh topic, I'm still confused by how one can understand and interpret this property of diagonalisation and how one can actually diagonalize in practice.

First and foremost, I've been trying to wrap my head around the following: let's take a fixed point $p \in M$ and consider the metric $g_p$ at this point $p$, and let $T(x)$ be it's representation as a matrix, where $x \in T_pM$.

From my understanding, the diagonalisation of $g_p$ would then be equipvalent to finding smooth eigenprojections for the representation matrix $T(x)$.

However, even for a smooth matrix function $T(x)$, the eigenspaces and eigenprojections do not need to behave smoothly or even exist everywhere. I found the following example in [this](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Eaar/papers/kato1.pdf) book by Kato, §5.3: Let $n = 2$, and:

$$T(x) = e^{- \frac 1{x^2}} \pmatrix{\cos \frac 2x & \sin \frac 2x \\ \sin \frac 2x & - \cos \frac 2x}, T(0) = 0$$

Then $T(x)$ is continuous and indefinitely differentiable for all real values of $x$, and the eigenvalues of $T(x)$ which turn out to be $\pm e^{- \frac 1 {x^2}}$ (for $x \neq 0$) and $0$ (for $x = 0$) are continuous and indefinitely differentiable aswell.

However, the eigenprojections for $x \neq 0$ in this case are:

$$ \pmatrix{\cos^2 \frac 1x & \cos \frac 1x \sin \frac 1x \\ \cos \frac 1x \sin \frac 1x & \sin^2 \frac 1x}, \pmatrix{ \sin^2 \frac 1x & - \cos \frac 1x \sin \frac 1x \\ - \cos \frac 1x \sin \frac 1x & \cos^2 \frac 1x}$$

These matrix functions are continuous and indefinitely differentiable on any interval that doesn't contain $0$, but they cannot be continued to $x = 0$ as continuous functions. Also, one can show that there doesn't exist any eigenvector of $T(x)$ that is continuous in the neighborhood of $x = 0$ and doesn't vanish in $x = 0$.

Sorry for this rather tedious example, but now my question is: Why is this not a contradiction to the diagonalisation? If according to Deturck and Yang all Riemannian metrics are locally diagonalizable for $n = 2, 3$, then why are there matrix functions like these that are not smoothly diagonalizable? Do these metric diagonalisations *not* correspond to finding the respective eigenprojection functions of the local metrix representation, and if so, why not? Or if there something else that I'm missing?

Any help would be much appreciated – maybe I'm just missing something very simple. I've been trying to wrap my head around this now for some days but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Moishe pointed out, you need to be careful to make the distinction between orthogonal/isothermal *coordinates* and orthogonal *frames* - the former is much stronger, while the latter always exist locally (by Gram-Schmidt). However, I think the crux of your question (the non-equivalence of a diagonalizing frame and frames aligned to the eigenspaces) still stands.

I believe the key issue is the distinction between the usual matrix diagonalization by the *similarity relation* $g = PDP^{-1}$, and the diagonalization by the  *congruence relation* $g = PDP^T$, which is what's going on here: we're diagonalizing a symmetric bilinear form, *without any requirement that the diagonalizing basis is orthonormal*. (Indeed, since we're attempting to diagonalize the metric, we don't have any natural "background" inner product.)

For similarity diagonalization, the diagonalizing basis $P$ is generically unique, and thus the regularity questions that Kato's book investigates are very natural. Congruence diagonalization of symmetric bilinear forms *by orthogonal transformations* is equivalent to similarity diagonalization (since $P^T = P^{-1}$ for orthogonal $P$), but if you're not making this restriction on $P$ then the situation is highly non-unique: if $g = PDP^T$ is positive definite, we can write this in the canonical form $g = (P \sqrt D) I (P \sqrt D)^T$, and in fact we have $g = (P \sqrt D O) I (P \sqrt D O)^T$ for any orthogonal $O.$ Thus the fact that $g$ is congruence-diagonalized in a given frame does *not* imply that this frame is aligned with the eigenprojections of $g$.

For a concrete example, consider the symmetric positive-definite matrix $$g=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 1\\
1 & 2
\end{array}\right),$$ which has orthogonal diagonalization $$
g=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
3 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{array}\right)^{-1}$$

but also many other congruence-diagonalizations, including

$$g=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
\frac{1}{2} & 1
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 0\\
0 & \frac{3}{2}
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
\frac{1}{2} & 1
\end{array}\right)^{T}.$$

Thus it shouldn't be too surprising that we can smoothly diagonalize a parametrized bilinear form in this sense, since we have a lot more room to move. Indeed, we always have existence of local orthonormal frames - you just take the usual Gram-Schmidt construction of an orthonormal basis, apply it to a smooth local frame and check that everything is smooth.

Answer (score 2):

> From my understanding, the diagonalisation of $g_p$ would then be equivalent to finding smooth eigenprojections for the representation matrix $T(x)$.

Your understanding is false already in the case $n=2$. I suggest you start by reading a proof of existence of isothermal coordinates in the 2d case. The difficult part to find a local diffeomorphism whose derivative at every $x$ sends eigenlines of $g_x$ in $T_xM$ to coordinate lines in the 3d space. In the 2d case this is relatively easy (generically) since the eigenlines of $g_x$ determine two transversal 1-dimensional foliations in  the plane and then you can map these foliations to the foliations by vertical and horizontal lines in the plane. This argument though breaks down already in the 2d case at a point where $g_x$ is already a scalar multiple of the Euclidean metric. The 3d case is even harder.

Edit. As for your example from Kato's book: The matrices $T(x)$ satisfy $T(0)=0$, which means that for $x=0$ the splitting to $R^2$ into a pair of 1-dimensional eigenspaces is undefined. (The eigenvalues are equal.) Therefore, you should not expect the  the eigenprojections to have a continuous extension to $x=0$. (The "genericity" assumption I made earlier means that the eigenvalues at every point are distinct.) The bottom line is that "diagonalization theorems" for metrics have very little to do with  eigenprojections.